# Android Studio Gradle Option Error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I went to re-sync my project to gradle, the option is grayed out. Why is this? How can I prevent this? I have tried opening new projects and the option is grayed out there as well. Additionally it worked earlier in the day.

Comment: How are you trying to sync your project ? are you using : `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` ?

Comment: When I go to do that the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" is grayed out.

Comment: @Amroelawar do you know anyone that might know the answer?